show/hide select2 with jQuery
I found a problem to display select2 options to load categories or products and I tested with every method and it didn't work. Even the options in the stackoverflow.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>0</title>

    <link href="../assets/cdn/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../assets/cdn/jq.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/cdn/select2.min.js"></script>

    <link href="../assets/css/style.bundle.rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .visible {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).on('change', '#cat', function() {
            $('#catlist').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
            $('#prolist').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
        });

        $(document).on('change', '#pro', function() {
            $('#prolist').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
            $('#catlist').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#catlist').select2();
            $('#prolist').select2();



            $.ajax({
                url: '../content/ajax/getcat.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                        $('#catlist').append('<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.faname + '</option>');
                    });
                    $('#cat').click(); 
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: '../content/ajax/getpro.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                        $('#prolist').append('<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.faname + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
                <div class="row p-4">
                    <label class="mb-3">Pro or Category</label>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-custom">
                            <input class="form-check-input" checked name="procat" type="radio" value="" id="cat" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="cat">category</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-custom">
                            <input class="form-check-input" name="procat" type="radio" value="" id="pro" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="pro">products</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <select class="form-select mb-3 hidden" id="catlist" data-control="select2" data-close-on-select="false" data-placeholder="select cats" data-allow-clear="true" multiple="multiple">
                </select>

                <select class="form-select mb-3 hidden" id="prolist" data-control="select2" data-close-on-select="false" data-placeholder="select products" data-allow-clear="true" multiple="multiple ">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>

I have not reached the result by using artificial intelligence and repeated questions in stackoverflow.


I'm win

<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none !important;
    }
    
    .visible {
        display: block !important;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function toggleContent() {
            if ($('#cat').is(':checked')) {
                $('#catlist').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
                $('#prolist').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
                $('#catlist').select2();
                $('#prolist').select2('destroy'); 
            } else if ($('#pro').is(':checked')) {
                $('#prolist').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
                $('#catlist').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
                $('#prolist').select2();
                $('#catlist').select2('destroy');
            }
        }


        $('input[name="procat"]').change(function() {
            toggleContent();
        });


        $.ajax({
            url: '../content/ajax/getcat.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#catlist').empty();
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    $('#catlist').append('<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.faname + '</option>');
                });
                toggleContent(); 
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '../content/ajax/getpro.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#prolist').empty(); 
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    $('#prolist').append('<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.faname + '</option>');
                });
                toggleContent(); 
            }
        });

        toggleContent();
    });
</script>


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
